# iOS 11 prefersLargeTitles with uibutton as title

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uinavigationbar

As titled, I'm using a UIButton as the titleView in the navbar. Is there a way for me to make the UIButton larger along with the navbar? When I set `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true`, what I got is this,

[image: larger navbar with regular title]

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any documentation on this, so I played a bit. It seems in iOS 11, you won't be able to get that title to be a button and display large at the left.

Also, I ttied playing with the frame size of the button (added below). I was unable to increase the button size, no matter what I set the frame to.

---

To recreate, I set up a Single View project. I embedded the view controller in a navigation controller.

In `ViewController.swift`'s `viewDidLoad`, I added this code:

```
    let titleButton = UIButton(type: .roundedRect)
    titleButton.setTitle("Hello Button!", for: UIControlState.normal)

    let navController = parent as! UINavigationController

    navController.navigationBar.topItem!.title = "Hello???"
    navController.navigationBar.topItem!.titleView = titleButton
    navController.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
```

This ends up looking something like your example.

**IF I**:

- set `.title` to empty string, or remark the line out: navbar is stretched, and no title text shows (or title text set in Interface Builder shows)
- remark out `.prefersLargeTitles`, or set it to `false`: the navbar is the normal height, the button displays, but no title text displays.
- remark out the `titleView` line, AND:

  - leave the `.prefersLargeTitles` set to `true`: the `title` text displays large at the left, and the navbar's height is stretched.
  - set the `.prefersLargeTitles` to `false`: the `title` text displays in the top center, and the navbar is normal height.